# DNS records - Site defualts to old https site

Tags: dns, https

I updated the DNS records for a site, which has a https version of the site. Instead of going to the new site which is http not https, the browsers will want to default to the old https version of the site. Is there a way to fix this issue?

The domain is registered with Dotster if that helps with how to manage the records.

the domain is:

http://sevenclanscasino.com

Comment: it's probably being redirected by the web server. If the server is apache you need to adjust the mod_rewrite. TO give you an answer I need to know what your webs server is... if its apache check this link https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL

Comment: @Logman I will check into what the server is running and get back to you ASAP.

Comment: Sorry I'm travelling so cannot do too much troubleshooting. However ignore HTTP or HTTPS DNS is for IP resolution so if you ping that domain name you'll get an IP returned is that correct? Or is that the old server? If the HTTPS redirection is causing an issue it's more likely to be on the web server itself as it has to get there to encounter the issue. Either this or your local computer cache is causing the issue and needs to be cleared as it's saved the old IP…

Comment: If the TTL is set high, it will take awhile for any changes to propagate across the Internet.  In other words, DNS servers will cache answers to queries (i.e., non-authoritative answers) until the TTL has expired.  Once the cached record has expired, the authoritative DNS server will be queried the next time someone does a lookup for the hostname.